# Irregular percentile tics in colorbar in GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot, colorbar

I have a text file which contains three columns: latitude, longitude and a percentage. The text file looks like this (link [here](http://www.gage.es/sites/default/files/gLAB/src/HeatMap_Test.txt)):

```
25.00  -28.00    0.3
25.00  -27.00    0.7
25.00  -26.00    1.6
25.00  -25.00    4.3
25.00  -24.00   10.0
25.00  -23.00   18.2
25.00  -22.00   33.9
25.00  -21.00   49.1
...
```

I want to plot this pertentages as a heatmap on top of a world map (the file for the world map for GNUPlot can be downloaded from the website author [here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/data/world_10m.txt))

The problem is with  the colorbar, which I want to group the values by irregular regions (percentiles). As it is difficult to explain, I am attaching an image if what I get with GNUPlot and another plot with the desired result:

GNUPlot try:
[image]

The code to generate the plot is:

```
set palette maxcolors 10
set palette defined (0 "#000090",1 "#000fff", 2 "#0090ff",3 "#0fffee",4 "#90ff70",5 "#ffee00",6 "#ff7000",7 "#ee0000",8 "#7f0000", 9 "#7f0050")
set cbtics (99.9 , 99.6, 99.0, 97.5, 95.0, 90.0, 75.0, 50.0, 20.0, 10.0);
plot [-30:40][25:70] "HeatMap_Test.txt" u 2:1:3 pt 5 ps 2 lc palette notitle, "world_10m.txt" with lines ls 1 notitle
```

Desired Result:
[image]

Besides from the colors in GNUPlot (which they are not the final ones), you can see that the colorbar tics distribute linearly (making the ones over 99.0 stick all toguether) and are not grouped by the regions defined by the colorbar tics.

Is there a way to do this plot in GNUPlot?

EDIT: The second part of the question continues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916407/contour-lines-with-labels-in-heatmap-with-gnuplot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a step function which maps the z column as needed.

```
reset

step(x) = (x < 15.0  ? 0 : \
          (x < 35.0  ? 1 : \
          (x < 62.5  ? 2 : \
          (x < 82.5  ? 3 : \
          (x < 92.5  ? 4 : \
          (x < 96.25 ? 5 : \
          (x < 98.25 ? 6 : \
          (x < 99.3  ? 7 : \
          (x < 99.75 ? 8 : 9 )))))))))

set palette maxcolors 10
set palette defined (0 "#333399", 1 "#3333f7", 2 "#3373ff", 3 "#33c6ff", \
                     4 "#5affd2", 5 "#9cff8f", 6 "#dfff4c", 7 "#ffc733", \
                     8 "#ff7a33", 9 "#e53333")

set cbrange [-0.5:9.5]
set cbtics nomirror
set cbtics ( "99.9" 9, "99.6" 8, "99.0" 7, "97.5" 6, "95.0" 5, \
             "90.0" 4, "75.0" 3, "50.0" 2, "20.0" 1, "10.0" 0 )

set terminal pngcairo
set output "output.png"
set xrange [-30:40]
set yrange [ 25:70]
plot "HeatMap_Test.txt" u 2:1:(step($3)) notitle pt 5 ps 2 lc palette, \
     "world_10m.txt" notitle with lines ls 1 lc -1
set output
```

I have nested the ternary operator several times to map the irregular percentage ranges 0 ... 100 into a linear `cbrange` -0.5 ... 9.5.

This is the result with Gnuplot 4.6:

[image: irregular percentile tics]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! It works perfect! You even got the colors right ! One final comment: Is there a way to make the borderlines fit the size of the image?